My manuscript was accepted 8 th of December and the Scholar One status showed accepted then awaiting to assignment to batch
My manuscript was accepted on 8th of December and the Scholar One status showed accepted then awaiting to assignment to batch since then without any change! Did I miss anything and how can I contact Sage production server to ensure that everything is ok?

It sound like, for that journal, papers are released in batches.  (In former times, they were released in issues and volumes.)  So it seems you do not need to do anything (except wait) unless they contact you.

It is a online first journal and i need to get publish to get my master degree i hope to get news soon .

Publishing is slow. You need to have more patience than 6 days.

You need to publish to get a masters degree? That is very unusual,  are you sure this is a real requirement?
